# Multiple writes to file

Tags: python, io, serial-port

I have the following python code that expects data coming from the serial port, and writes it to a file.

```
import time
import serial

def write_log ( text ):
    f = open('logger.log', 'a')
    f.write( text )
    f.close()

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyS0"
ser.baudrate = 4800
ser.open()
if ser.isOpen():
    while 1:
        while ser.inWaiting() <= 0:
            time.sleep(1)
            response = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
            if len ( response ):
                write_log( response )
                print response
```

It works to an extent, as after some time, it starts to hang, bringing the CPU all the way up, and not writing anything (or sometimes writing only pieces of text) to the .log file.

The process here is pretty intensive, as my serial port will be writing an 8 bytes string every second, and this python script is supposed to then receive it, and write its contents to the log file.

I'm thinking the problem here is the fact that I'm opening and closing the file too much, and this is somehow making the whole process slow. I'm no python wizz, so any help or advice on improving this code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: 8 bytes per second is not very intensive; 8 MiB/s might be intensive, but most CPUs can cope with even that.  Even a Z80 running at 4 MHz would not find 8 bytes per second intensive.

Comment: I do realize it's not very intensive, but somehow this code stops responding after some time, and stops storing anything. I say intensive, because it will keep trying to write stuff into serial, even if the python script isn't writing anything into the text file

Comment: The code looks to be reading from the serial device, not writing to it.

Comment: "I have the following python code that expects data coming from the serial port, and writes it to a file."

Reads from serial and writes contents from it to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are polling for updates.

Python's `serial.read()` function actually blocks the current thread until something becomes readable on the thread, until timeout. What you should do, therefore, is break out another thread to handle serial IO. Have it loop indefinitely, checking a condition (the master thread wants you to stay listening and the serial port is still available). This thread will do something like:

```
while ser.isOpen() && thisthread_should_keep_doing_this:
    response = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
    if len(response):
        write_log(response)
        print response
```

Then, when you want it to exit, your master thread sets `thisthread_should_keep_doing_this=False` and when your slave thread has finished reading, it kills itself.

Two things:

- Do have the read timeout relatively frequently.
- Do not "remote kill" the thread. Pass it a message and have it kill itself. Killing threads remotely creates an awful mess.

See http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html#miniterm

Comment: Not sure I really understand what's to be done here. Again, I'm no python wizz, and have never worked with threads in it. Your idea however seems like a sensible solution to my problem

Comment: @Marcos the idea is quite simple, but really hard to get your head around, if that makes sense. Basically, blocking IO is like sleep. Your thread will wake up on two conditions: data comes out, or the delay expires. What you then do is check the port is open and you don't want to be exiting, then try and read again and let the read block away. By creating two threads, you can sacrifice one to this purpose and one to get on with the main business of the program (even if that is just waiting for the "exit" instruction).

Comment: With blocking IO like this, if there's lots of data coming in, you read it instantaneously. If there isn't, you sleep for the timeout interval. With YOUR solution, you sleep for 1 second and pull whatever's there. So for that 1 second, you could be using clock cycles to read data, but instead you're not. Then there's loads of data... and you get unpredictable results.

Comment: I've never done threads in Python either. I did C with Serial IO on Windows and THE way to do it is blocking IO.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop in your code, and you don't break out from it when there is a problem - or the serial device is no longer open.

Probably use:

```
while ser.isOpen():
    while ser.inWaiting() <= 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        response = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        if len(response):
            write_log(response)
            print response
```

or even:

```
while ser.isOpen() && ser.inWaiting() <= 0:
    time.sleep(1)
    response = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
    if len(response):
        write_log(response)
        print response
```

I'm not sure about the sleep, either; you'd do better just waiting in the read for data to become available.

As I think about it, not knowing the methods available in the serial class, the more I think the main loop should be attempting to read from the serial device, hanging happily if there is nothing currently available, and only terminating when the input method indicates there is no more input to come - the device has been closed on you, or has failed in some way.

Comment: Your example dies after some time as well

Comment: @Marcos: OK, but without a specification of the serial package (is that standard Python?  I doubt it) it is going to be difficult to know what you need to do.  Doubly so since I can only really read Python and not write it fluently.  But you should aim to have the loop (singular - not nested) read synchronously; it simply hangs in the read until there is data ready.  If that function is not available already, then you may want to write a function to provide it.  If you really need to poll, you might want to poll more frequently than once per second, using a micro-sleep function.